# Prove that a matrix can be written as a sum of permutation matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, permutation-matrices, stochastic-matrices, birkhoff-polytopes

> Given a square matrix $A$ of size $n$ whose entries are non-negative integers and where the sum of each column and row is equal to $k$, prove that $A$ can be written as a sum of $k$ permutation matrices.

---

First, it is obvious to see that a sum o $k$ permutation matrices will result in a matrix where the rows and columns sums to $k$. By [Birkhoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix), any doubly stochastic matrix can be written as a linear combination of permutation matrices,

$$\frac{1}{k}A = \sum_{i=1}^{r}{c_i P_i}$$

$$A = k \left(\sum_{i=1}^{r}{c_i P_i}\right)$$

where $c_i > 0$ is a real coefficient and $P_i$ is a permutation matrix. However, my solution can have more than $k$ permutation matrices (because the $c_i$ can be less than $1$) and each one with a real coefficient and question asks for just a sum of $k$ permutation matrices (so $c_i = 1$).

---

Some related questions that guided me:

1. [Characterizing sums of permutation matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583874/characterizing-sums-of-permutation-matrices)
2. [Is it possible to solve for values in a matrix such that all rows and columns have equal sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1636593/is-it-possible-to-solve-for-values-in-a-matrix-such-that-all-rows-and-columns-have-equal-sum%3F#answer-1637295)
3. [Prove the existence of a permutation for a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778670/prove-the-existence-of-a-permutation-for-a-matrix#comment-1615325)

Comment: Related: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214948/339790), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1163680/339790).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use induction on $k$. The base case $k=1$ is clear. If $k>1$, then by Birkhoff's theorem you cited (or by Hall's marriage lemma), there is some permutation matrix  $P$
so that $P_{ij}>0$ implies $A_{ij}>0$  (any $P$ that is part of the Birkhoff decomposition of $A/k$ will do.) For this $P$, the $n \times n$ matrix  $A-P$ has  non-negative integer entries, and the sum of each column and row of $A-P$ is equal to $k-1$.By the inductive hypothesis,
$A-P$ can be written as a sum of $k-1$ permutation matrices, whence $A$
can be written as a sum of $k$ permutation matrices.